# SUM case returns value without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, case

When I add SUM around my case select, it returns the summed value without the GROUP BY.

The query I am using, without the SUM, is the following

```
SELECT CASE WHEN subscription_types.type  = 'Succes lidmaatschap' THEN 7 ELSE 8 END FROM subscription_used
INNER JOIN training_sessions ON  training_sessions.id = subscription_used.training_session_id
INNER JOIN training_series AS tserie ON tserie.id = training_sessions.training_serie_id
INNER JOIN user_training_session ON user_training_session.training_session_id = training_sessions.id
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.id = subscription_used.subscription_id
INNER JOIN subscription_types ON subscription_types.id = subscriptions.subscription_type_id
WHERE subscription_used.training_session_id =  (SELECT training_sessions.id FROM training_sessions WHERE DATE(event_start_date) = @week_2_ago_date AND training_serie_id = 17) AND present=1
GROUP BY subscriptions.id
```

This query returns the values: 8,7. However, when I put a SUM around the case, it gives me the number 75. 75 is the SUM of the values that are getting returned without the GROUP BY.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem so that the query gives me the correct value (8+7  = 15, 1 row)? Thanks in advance

Comment: What ___should___ be returned?

Comment: The value that should be returned is the SUM of the group by, which is 8+7 = 15

Comment: also give us some data so we can figure out what is happening exactly

Comment: `SUM(DISTINCT CASE ....)`?

Comment: Have you tried just putting everything inside a `SELECT SUM(1) FROM ( ... )`

Comment: [Here](http://gyazo.com/bd66dd84ef1568e08cefc218e346fe5c) you can see the values that it returns from the query in the answer.
[Here](http://gyazo.com/57610f88f998dd6fce4bcda1aaac7531) without the group by
[Here](http://gyazo.com/10dbad2128aa7719e351cde2cd35388f) the sum with the group by

Comment: You do a `GROUP BY subscriptions.id` and mysql will return any row for each id. When you remove the `GROUP BY` you will notice that there are multiple rows with `7`and `8`

Comment: @dnoeth Sometimes, there more then 2 values which means if it returns 7,8,8, it will only return 7,8, correct?

Comment: It will return any row, might be (7, 8) or (8,8) or (7,7)

Comment: @OriolBG Yes, I have tried this. This returns [these results](http://gyazo.com/10dbad2128aa7719e351cde2cd35388f)

Comment: @dnoeth I only want 1 row with everything summed up, so I need to get rid of the GROUP BY. Will DISTINCT do the same as GROUP BY did without the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by is implying distinct values based on subscription.id  so probably if you take the group by you you will get something like 8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7 due to the joins and such.

With the group by you only get the distinct values of 8 and 7.  When you do sum with the group it will sum all of them though not the 2 distinct.

Most Simple fix that will give you 15:

```
SELECT SUM(SUBSCRIPTION_USED) FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN subscription_types.type  = 'Succes lidmaatschap' THEN 7 ELSE 8 END FROM subscription_used
INNER JOIN training_sessions ON  training_sessions.id = subscription_used.training_session_id
INNER JOIN training_series AS tserie ON tserie.id = training_sessions.training_serie_id
INNER JOIN user_training_session ON user_training_session.training_session_id = training_sessions.id
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.id = subscription_used.subscription_id
INNER JOIN subscription_types ON subscription_types.id = subscriptions.subscription_type_id
WHERE subscription_used.training_session_id =  (SELECT training_sessions.id FROM training_sessions WHERE DATE(event_start_date) = @week_2_ago_date AND training_serie_id = 17) AND present=1
GROUP BY subscriptions.id);
```

Probably a better way to write it in general though.

EDIT:  You could also do SUM(DISTINCT CASE......)  if you only want to sum distinct values.

Comment: This works on itself, however, when I try to use it in a subquery where I replace _AND training_serie_id = 17_ to _AND training_serie_id = tserie_id_, it can't find the tserie table. This tserie table is an alias from outside the subquery _(INNER JOIN training_series AS tserie ON tserie.id = session.training_serie_id)_ Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You are already joining tserie.id on training_session.training_serie_id externally.  Maybe you are looking more for this?:
`SELECT SUBSCRIPTION_ID, SUM(VAL) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSCRIPTION_ID, (CASE WHEN subscription_types.type  = 'Succes lidmaatschap' THEN 7 ELSE 8 END) AS VAL
FROM subscription_used INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.id = subscription_used.subscription_id
 INNER JOIN subscription_types ON subscription_types.id = subscriptions.subscription_type_id`

Comment: `INNER JOIN training_sessions ON  training_sessions.id = subscription_used.training_session_id
 INNER JOIN user_training_session ON user_training_session.training_session_id = training_sessions.id
 INNER JOIN training_series AS tserie ON tserie.id = training_sessions.training_serie_id
WHERE DATE(training_sessions.event_start_date) = @week_2_ago_date
AND PRESENT = 1)
GROUP BY SUBSCRIPTION_ID;`